# Identifying which global variable is allocated by which shared library

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, dynamic-loading, dlsym, dladdr

Assume there are shared libraries lib1, lib2, etc. each declaring and using one of its own global variable g_lib1, g_lib2, etc. I have the addresses of g_lib1, g_lib2, etc., as well as the names of the global variables, but I do not know which variable came from which shared library. My aim is to write a function that can do that.

Using dladdr() on the addresses did not work as it errors out. Furthermore, using dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, "name") also reports it as invalid symbol (even though I can see them when using "nm -D" on the executable) .Furthermore, the addresses for all the global variables even if from different libraries are shown to be contiguous and not in the address space of any shared library, which I couldn't understand why.

Is there a way I can programmatically map the global variables to the shared libraries that defined them (like we can map functions to shared libraries with dladdr() using their return address)?

Comment: **Why** do you need to know this? What is the actual problem that knowledge is supposed to solve? Please ask about that problem directly, otherwise your question is just another [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: This is a requirement for an application that gives users insights on when, where and how much memory has been allocated by your program when it is being run. I want to add which dynamically loaded library is responsible for each allocation.

Comment: Counting the number of individual variables will give you a false result for that. Get the libraries initialized- and uninitialized-data segments, and you will get the number. Or just look through the `/proc` files for the process to find the complete memory map.

Comment: Thanks for this response. I do have the number of variables updated as and when they are created, but I want to attribute each allocation to its source (i.e. which shared library is responsible for this allocation), so that users will know when and how much each shared library allocates memory. Is there a way for that?

Comment: I think you misunderstand either your task, or how memory is handled for variables, or the task itself is flawed. Global variables aren't allocated one by one, and they are not allocated when they are used. Instead the compiler puts all global variables in one of two segments that are allocated as a whole when the library is loaded. If you check `/proc/<pid>/maps` you will get a complete memory map, which will list the different segments used by the individual libraries that are loaded.

Comment: To expand on the problem, once built. the program or library doesn't really have "variables" as such, all the program have is some memory addresses where it can load and store bits, bytes and words. All global initialized variables will end up in a single `data` segment, which will likely contain padding. If you want to know how much memory a library uses, you need to count the padding as well, because it will be included in the memory usage of the library.

Comment: Thanks you for this detailed explanation! I checked the /proc/<pid>/maps for the program and unfortunately, the allocations I wished to track fall under an anonymous map, and didnt have the source library path. I now realize this is where dladdr() also gets the source library from. Since the same approach works for functions, I had assumed it can extend to global and static allocations as well, now I see why that doesn't work.

Comment: From the value returned by malloc/calloc/realloc/mmap/break/sbreak/etc you cannot determine the calling component.